# Angular table column add with spinner

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am making a project with angular 14 and angular material. I have a table. There is an update button next to each staff member. I want the spinner on the button of the employee I click to work, but they all work, so it is not clear which employee's information is updated. What do I need to do to make the spinner of the staff I just clicked on work. I would be glad if you help.

```
            <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" filterControl="true">
                        <thead class=" text-primary">
                            <th>NAME</th>
                            <th>SURNAME</th>
                            <th>DATE</th>
                          
                            <th></th>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let personel of dataPersonel ">
                                <td> <b>{{personel.name}}</b> </td>
                                <td> {{personel.surname}}</td>
                                <td> {{personel.date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button mat-raised-button
                                        class="btn btn-info" (click)="updatePerspnel(personel)">
                                        UPDATE
                                        <mat-icon *ngIf="loading">
                                            <mat-spinner color="primary" diameter="20"> </mat-spinner>
                                        </mat-icon>
                                    </button>


                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

---

```
 loading: boolean = false;
  ngOnInit(): void {
  
  }


   updatePerspnel(personel) {
     this.loading = true;
     this.personelService.updatePersonel(personel).subscribe(response => {
          if (response === Constants.OK) {
            this.alertifyService.makeSuccess();
          }else{
           this.alertifyService.makeError();
          }
          this.loading = false;
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the spinner on the button of the employee you clicked work without affecting the spinners on other buttons, you need to track the loading state for each employee separately. You can achieve this by adding a `loading` property to each employee object in your `dataPersonel` array. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

1. Update your component to include a `loading` property for each employee in the `dataPersonel` array.

```js
dataPersonel: any[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
  // Initialize your dataPersonel array here
  this.loadDataPersonel();
}

loadDataPersonel() {
  // Fetch your employee data and populate the dataPersonel array
}

updatePerspnel(personel) {
  personel.loading = true; // Set the loading state for the specific employee
  this.personelService.updatePersonel(personel).subscribe(response => {
    if (response === Constants.OK) {
      this.alertifyService.makeSuccess();
    } else {
      this.alertifyService.makeError();
    }
    personel.loading = false; // Reset the loading state for the specific employee
  });
}
```

2. Update your HTML template to use the `loading` property for each employee to conditionally display the spinner:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let personel of dataPersonel ">
  <td> <b>{{personel.name}}</b> </td>
  <td> {{personel.surname}}</td>
  <td> {{personel.date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
  <td>
    <button mat-raised-button class="btn btn-info" (click)="updatePerspnel(personel)">
      UPDATE
      <mat-icon *ngIf="personel.loading"> <!-- Use personel.loading to control the spinner -->
        <mat-spinner color="primary" diameter="20"> </mat-spinner>
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

By adding a `loading` property to each employee object and using it to control the spinner display, you ensure that only the spinner for the clicked employee will be shown while the update operation is in progress. This way, it's clear which employee's information is being updated.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a `personnel` object, i recommend you to declare a new property inside of it called `isLoading`, it can be a simple boolean set by default to `false`

(I personnaly recommend creating a property `status` with an enum for it, to provide more readability and consistency)

After that in your template

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" filterControl="true">
                        <thead class=" text-primary">
                            <th>NAME</th>
                            <th>SURNAME</th>
                            <th>DATE</th>
                          
                            <th></th>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let personel of dataPersonel ">
                                <td> <b>{{personel.name}}</b> </td>
                                <td> {{personel.surname}}</td>
                                <td> {{personel.date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button mat-raised-button
                                        class="btn btn-info" (click)="updatePerspnel(personel)">
                                        UPDATE
                                        <mat-icon *ngIf="personel.isLoading">
                                            <mat-spinner color="primary" diameter="20"> </mat-spinner>
                                        </mat-icon>
                                    </button>


                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Then in your logic

```
 loading: boolean = false;
  ngOnInit(): void {
  
  }


   updatePerspnel(personel) {
     personel.isLoading = true;
     this.personelService.updatePersonel(personel).subscribe(response => {
          if (response === Constants.OK) {
            this.alertifyService.makeSuccess();
          }else{
           this.alertifyService.makeError();
          }
          personel.isLoading = false;
        });

    }
```